# Storing multiple parameters with different values using arrays in JSON

Tags: arrays, json

I'm having 3 classes namely A, B and C...!
Each class having different parameters, i.e, A-->a,b,c,d,e,f,  B--> g,h,i,j and C--> k,l,m,n...!
Each parameter having 4 values namely min,max,def and cur...!

Is it correct way in JSON as am new to JSON..!

```
var obj = {
            "A": {
                "a": { "Default": 0.0, "Current": 30.0, "Min": 0.0, "Max": 200.0 },
                "b": { "Default": 0.0, "Current": 60.0, "Min": 0.0, "Max": 10.44 },
                "c": { "Default": 0.0, "Current": 60.0, "Min": 0.0, "Max": 89.0 },
                "d": { "Default": 1.0, "Current": 60.0, "Min": 1.0, "Max": 255.0 },
                "e": { "Default": 1.0, "Current": 60.0, "Min": 1.0, "Max": 255.0 },
                "f": false
            },
            "B": {
                "g": { "Default": 0.0, "Current": 15.0, "Min": 10.0, "Max": 20.4 },
                "h": { "Default": 1.0, "Current": 120.0, "Min": 1.0, "Max": 255.0 },
                "i": { "Default": 0.0, "Current": 60.0, "Min": 0.0, "Max": 10.44 },
                "j": { "Default": 1.0, "Current": 60.0, "Min": 1.0, "Max": 255.0 }
            },
            "C": {
                "k": { "Default": 0.0, "Current": 10.0, "Min": 0.0, "Max": 3.06 },
                "l": { "Default": 1.0, "Current": 3.5, "Min": 0.0, "Max": 2.55 },
                "m": { "Default": 0.0, "Current": 3.0, "Min": 0.0, "Max": 2.55 },
                "n": { "Default": 0.0, "Current": 401.0, "Min": 0.0, "Max": 1270.0 }
            }
        }
```

I appreciate for any suggestion on this..!

Comment: If you're new to JSON, please start off by learning what JSON is and what it is not. What you are trying to do here has nothing to do with JSON; it has to do with **JavaScript objects**, which is an entirely different thing. No, what you are trying to do is not the right approach. A `key: value` pair may only occur **within** an object. What are you expecting your variables called `obja` etc. to do, and how are you expecting them to behave? Also, whatever these things are supposed to be, they are not "classes", which means something else altogether. By the way, there is no need to quote keys.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/json/889/introduction-to-json

Comment: Also, your title refers to "arrays", but there is nothing in your question that has anything to do with arrays, which are lists of things represented in literal form using square brackets `[]`. I suggest you start off by revisiting some basic tutorials on JS data types.

Comment: you can validate your json at jsonlint.com

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.